# Ruby tag in javascript function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js

I have a grid of promo codes where there is an option to edit the values of a promo code. Selecting edit opens up a modal and fills the modal with the promo code's values from the db.

I have this function call on my edit buttons:

```
'v-on:click.prevent': 'showEditPromoCodeModal("#edit_promo_code_<%= promo_code.id %>")'
```

Each modal is prepared in the background to be opened with the relevant id:

```
<% @promo_codes.each do |promo_code| %>
  <div id="edit_promo_code_<%= promo_code.id %>" class="ui small modal">
    <%= render "admin/promo_codes/edit", promo_code: promo_code %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The function opens one of these modals selecting the corresponding modal by id:

```
showEditPromoCodeModal: function(modal_id) {
  $(modal_id).modal({
    observeChanges: true,
    onApprove : function() {
      $(modal_id + " .positive.button").addClass("loading");
      $(modal_id + " form").submit();
      return false;
    },
  }).modal('show');
},
```

This works if I hard code:

```
showEditPromoCodeModal("#edit_promo_code_1")
```

I'm wondering if its possible to use a ruby tag in this way:

```
showEditPromoCodeModal("#edit_promo_code_<%= promo_code.id %>")
```

Looks like there is an issue in the ruby tag syntax being recognized while inside a javascript function call, but is fine in plain html. I get the error "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end" a few lines later. If this is not possible, I assume I would have to prepare the id string outside and insert it there.

Edit:

Replaced my link_to method with just the html I needed to call the modal.

I modified the way I call through the grid to:

```
g.column name: "Edit Code", attribute: 'id' do |promo_code|
  "<span v-on:click='showEditPromoCodeModal(#edit_promo_code_#{promo_code.id})' class='ui green label'>Edit</span".html_safe
end
```

The method actually loaded correctly but resulted in another error:

https://i.gyazo.com/4827b7f8de80a4b306003f5911703b96.png

The issue seems to be with calling vue-js inside the wice grid. I had no problem calling vue-js in the wice grid when I hard coded (in link_to method):

```
showEditPromoCodeModal("#edit_promo_code_1")
```

When only using html in the wice grid, vue-js is suddenly an invalid expression but the ruby tag works. Is there any way to let both work or is this a fundamental issue? I have this same functionality implemented with a javascript grid that calls v-on:click="method(#updateX_<%= X.id %> to open up the method.

Comment: as long as in html.erb page, it works just make sure its in double quotes always `var xxx = "<%= 5*5 %>"`

Comment: I see you have a `v-on`, but the rest of this code is not Vue, and you can't mix Vue and non-Vue DOM-manipulating code this way. Vue or Vue not.

Comment: I've updated the post with some info that points to this conclusion. Is there any way to pass the promo_code.id variable to vue such that I can open the modal? Since everything else is set up correctly, its only a matter of selecting the right modal to open on click.